# Why doesn't NSThread's cancel method call pthread_cancel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, pthreads, nsthread

Apple's documentation, and all the open source implementations I can find, are in agreement that thread cancellation should be handled entirely by the user. That is, `[thread cancel]` just sets a `BOOL` property on the receiver. It's then up to the user's implementation to check `[NSThread currentThread].isCancelled` periodically and, if `YES`, prematurely return from the thread's `main` method.

Okay, fair enough. But why not instead rely on `pthread_cancel`, which has dozens of builtin cancellation points already implemented? Surely this would yield more responsive thread cancellation. `NSThread` could easily be extended to have a `cancellationBlock` property, or some other mechanism for user-defined cancellation behavior that `NSThread` itself could dispatch via `pthread_cleanup_pop`.

Did Apple think this would be too complicated for people to use or something? The rest of the `NSThread` API is basically 1:1 with the `pthreads` API, so I'm curious why a different (honestly naive) path was chosen here.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question fully. Are you asking if there is a way to get signaled when thread is cancelled ?

Comment: Nope, I'm just curious as to the decision in implementing `NSThread`'s cancel mechanism this way. `NSThread` is built on `pthreads` and exposes basically a 1:1 API with the POSIX threads API -- *except* for `cancel`. Why?

Comment: I cant tell for sure as to why cancel is present. But my best guess would be because NSThread is KVO complaint. So you can have someone observing your thread and someone else cancel it with a simple cancel message.